# SSRS Print logo between Body and footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Hi I need to create a SSRS report that has a logo that prints half at body and another half at footer.

This is my requirement:

[image]

Actually if I paste the logo at footer it can't enlarge to body 
If I paste it into Body, cant enlarge it to footer it only makes body grow.

An this is my best! :(

[image]

Is this posible ?
How ?

Comment: Maybe if you had a predefined height for the body (i.e, it never changes) and line up two images, one in body, one in footer. Could be tricky lining them up.

Comment: Can't you get rid of footer and handle both part in body? Like may be in a grouping your content.

Comment: The @p2k 's suggestion is a very possible solution to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have elements like images and tables overlap in SSRS. The only way to make this work is to have that logo as part of the `background image`. So you'll need to edit an image that has the logo in the desired position ahead of time and then use that as the background.